# Firebase with cordova : webapp or android app

Tags: cordova, firebase, firebase-notifications

I am creating a new Firebase push notification for android, a cordova based app.

Any references on what is the best options to select : web app vs android app in firebase.

1. Are there any differences in using either or both are same
2. Will the messages be persistent for days.

Comment: yes.. push notification

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any differences in using either or both are same
>
> Will the messages be persistent for days.

It does not really matter, cordova is used to target multiple platform using web langauges like : HTML/CSS & JS. Firebase is a service that supports web/ios/android. So you can integrate firebase also in cordova.

For more info check this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Cordova targets multiple platform while android only targets android phones. Regarding firebase in the two it is basically the same, both have the same queries and both can use `cloud functions`  to send notifications.

Regarding second question, messages will stay there until the user dismisses them.